# compare datetime var to str var

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare a `datetime.datetime.now()` variable to a `calendar.itermonthdates()` variable.

According to the errors I'm getting, the datetime.now is a datetime.date() type, whereas the 
itermonthdates is a string.

how can I convert the datetime date to a string for comparison?

and will string comparison work for dates of the format 2011-12-12? I'm not sure how string comparsion functions in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates), `calendar.itermonthdates` should return a datetime.date object :

> Return an iterator for the month month (1-12) in the year year. This
>   iterator will return all days (as **datetime.date** objects) for the month
>   and all days before the start of the month or after the end of the
>   month that are required to get a complete week.

If you have strings, check (and post in your question) your code

Comment: That's what I thought, but the error said str. Anyways, I found a better way to do what I was trying to achieve, which was to iterate through the days from the current date. Using `datetime.timedelta` worked just fine.